# Имитация нажатия enter в определенном input`e

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать данную функцию? мне нужно отправлять в чат сообщения без перезагрузки страницы, как это происходит просто при нажатии кнопки Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input.onkeydown = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) { // Enter
        console.log('send message: ' + input.value);
    }
}
```