# js Ввод с кнопки

Tags: javascript

Происходит ввод данных в поле (input) и получение значения с кнопки "Жмакни меня":

```js
function someFunc() {
  alert(document.getElementById("txt").value);
}
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = someFunc;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Жмакни меня">
```

Как сделать так, что бы ввод был с помощью клавиши на клавиатуре *Enter*?

Comment: Повесить соответствующего слушателя на вводимый input

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Имитация нажатия enter в определенном input\`e](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521124/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-enter-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-inpute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function func(event) {
  if(event.keyCode==13) {
    alert(document.getElementById("txt").value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="func(event)" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Жмакни меня">
```

Comment: Cпасибо всем большое, помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Можно как то так

```js
someFunc();
function someFunc () {
    let input = document.getElementById('txt'),
        btn   = document.getElementById('btn');
    
    // Отлавливаем нажатие клавиш в input
    input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        // Если это клавиша Enter
        if (event.keyCode == 13) alert(input.value);
    });
    
    // Нажатие по кнопке не убирал
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert(input.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Жмакни меня">
```

> [Коды клавиш](https://keycode.info/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode ( deprecated ), хоть и работает) Можно заменить на "code"

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Спасибо